# Can two peers share the same CouchDB container?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

can two peer containers of the same org share the same CouchDB database on Fabric v2.0?

Answer (score 0):

No, They don't share same couchdb. Every peer maintain its own couchdb and communicate via gossip protocol to be in sync with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No

Few points to support this, as below:

- CouchDB is used as a state database by the peers
- Every peer has an identity and it has to be a separate couch instance in order to store the state data
- state data may contains public data and private data when you enable private data mode and it has to be separate and dedicated  instance